# How to open a URL in private browser xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I want to open a url in the Mobile/Tablet browser, private browsing is needed because sigin is required for some of the url. I don't want to leave the cookies behind. Is there any way to do it?

Right now I am using following code to open the browser:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://www.google.co.in"));

Comment: I don't think there is a way to start the browser in Private mode (iOS) or Incognito mode (Android). So the workaround would be to use one of the below answers to clean up the cookies after using a `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

you create an activity where you simply show a web browser.
When this activity destory i.e.

```
void onDestory(){
   // remove cookie
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookies(callback);
}
```

remove all cookies

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create an interface (ex: `IWebHelper`). In `IWebHelper` add the following single method:

```
public void DeleteAllCookies();
```

The in Android and iOS, create `WebHelper` and implement the `DeleteAllCookies()` method like so:

iOS:

```
public void DeleteAllCookies() { foreach(NSHttpCookie cookie in _storage.Cookies) { _storage.DeleteCookie(cookie); } }
```

Android:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes all cookies stored in the CookieManager on Android.
/// </summary>
public void DeleteAllCookies() {
    if(_cookieManager.HasCookies) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) {
            _cookieManager.RemoveAllCookies(null);
        } else { _cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie(); }
    }
}
```

Not sure about Windows Phone.

Comment: What is the reason for handling Lollipop and greater versions differently?

Comment: @Ethan Android has a lot of APIs that are introduced in later version or are deprecated in later versions and so it requires you to run different methods depending on the version. `CookieManager.RemoveAllCookies()` is one such method. If you head to [Android's SDK Docs for that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#removeAllCookie()), you will see the message that it was deprecated in API 21 and recommends the version where a callback is passed in. You can also see right below it that the callback version of the method was not introduced until API 21